# Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.email'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, es6-promise

I want to save a new node or object users to firebase database, but it gives me the error first argument contains undefined.
I am unable to fix this error. Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong?

```
class Authen extends Component {

    login(event) {
        const email = this.refs.email.value;
        const password = this.refs.password.value;
        console.log(email,password);

        const auth = firebase.auth();
        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        promise.catch((e) => {
            var err = e.message;
            console.log("The error is ",err);
            this.setState({err: err});
        });
    }

    signup(event) {
        const email = this.refs.email.value;
        const password = this.refs.password.value;
        console.log(email,password);

        const auth = firebase.auth();
        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password); 

        promise
        .then(user => {
            var err = "Welcome "+user.email;
            firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.uid).set({
                email: user.email
            });
            console.log("The user is ",user);
            this.setState({err: err});
        });
        promise
        .catch(e => {
            var err = e.message;
            console.log(err);
            this.setState({err: err});
        });
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            err: ''
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input id="email" ref="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" /><br />
                <input id="pass" ref="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" /><br />
                <p>{this.state.err}</p>
                <button onClick={this.login}>Log In</button>
                <button onClick={this.signup}>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Authen;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and the reason is that received `promise` used in wrong way. You need to go deeper and use `email` and `uid` properties inside `user` object in response.

In other words, change

1. `user.email` to `user.user.email`
2. `user.uid` to `user.user.uid`.

   `var err = "Welcome "+ user.user.email
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.user.uid).set({
        email: user.user.email
     });`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, I think firebase has some other error and assumes you are passing through a .child which leads to the reference error.

Try setting email to be a string and then retyping user.email.